# How to declare a method with arrays in main?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I wrote this in my `main` because I want to call this method bla_methods from my main.
I wrote an method called bla_methods already. The main isn't letting me call my bla_method. 
Sorry, I should have clarified myself. But, thanks everyone!

```
bla_methods (one_data[], two_datas[], length);
```

then I get this error for `one_data[]` and `two_datas[]`

```
<<gradeabc.java:45: error: '.class' expected >>
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods cannot be nested.

You can only create a method directly inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

You declare methods within your class, but outside of other methods (unless it's a method in an inner class)...

```
public static void bla_methods (String[] one_data, int[] two_datas, int length) {
  // do something.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  // ...
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

No, Java doesn't allow you to define methods inside of other methods - main included.

Just put the method inside the same class as main.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified the data type of the array, that's why you got the error.

```
private static void bla_methods (DATA_TYPE[] one_data, DATA_TYPE[] two_data, int length){
    //your code
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    bla_methods(a, b, c);
    //
}
```

the "DATA_TYPE" int bla_method can be any data type. such as int, float etc. it can also be an Object of a class, such String...

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand a few things to be able to work in Java:

1. Everything, methods and members are parts of either a class or an object. By inside I mean they are inside their block, marked by {}.
2. A class is declared by the `class` keyword followed by the name of the class. Example: `class foo {/*...*/}`
3. An object is an instance of a class, which is usually instantiated by the `new` keyword. Example `Foo bar = new Foo();`
4. Members can be members of an object or a class (if they are `static`). They have a type and they might have an initial value. Example: `Foo bar = new Foo();`
5. Methods can be methods of an object or a class (if they are `static`). Methods have a return type, a parameter list and a block of their own, where the exact receipt/algorithm of the method is defined. Example: static `public void main(String args[]){/*...*/}`
6. Members represent the state of the object/class where they are applicable.
7. Methods represent the ability of the object/class where they are applicable.
8. A parameter is inside the brackets of a method, they have a type as well. Example: `public static void main(String args[]){/*...*/}`
9. A variable behaves almost like a member, but it is defined inside a method and is applicable only there.

I think you should read a tutorial, for example [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) one.

So, you did not associate a type to your variables/parameters and I doubt that your method was defined correctly.

Comment: actually, i fix it.
bla_methods (one_data[], two_datas[], length);
i discarded the [];
now i have rounding problems 
70.63859338365493
i'm ganna look for how to get rid of those nums. Thanks !

Comment: Shelliee, first of all, if you have a completely different question, then ask it in a separate question. Secondly, you did not fix anything, as you wanted to "declare" (maybe call?) a method with arrays in main. Getting rid of the [] did not solve your problem, because then you no longer have arrays.

Comment: actually, i fix it. my program runs and i'm getting the right nums. and 2ndly, i know to ask another question else where, but i just wrote it here cause i thought this  was a conversation; i was wrong.

Comment: No, you are totally wrong. Your questions was "How to declare a method with arrays in main?". It is not about your calculations, it is about "writing" a method in main. I was addressing your question. And you cannot answer your question by getting rid of the arrays. I believe you that you have managed to do your task, but the way you have done it does not answer your question. You clearly do not understand much about programming so please, read my answer with more attention. Especially the part where I tell you that you should look at some tutorials.